# How do you slice a string into unique letters in a list?

Tags: python

Simple question: how do you slice a string like "john rohn bohn" into unique letters - `["j", "o", "h", "n", "r", "b"]`?
So far I have tried:

```
og = "john rohn bohn"
new = list(set(og))
print(new)
```

The only problem is that the `set()` method isn't really slicing the list.

Comment: What is the problem with the result so ? Also "slicing" isn't that, slicing is cutting one string part, what you want it just split on every letter

Comment: Do you want to keep order ? and no space ?

Comment: I believe the intent is to keep first occurence of each letter.

Comment: Is the issue that the order is not preserved or is the issue that a space is currently allowed or is it both or something else? Without clarification on the actual issue, your code seems to work fine to me,

Comment: one-liner (not quite as efficient as a loop that uses both a set and a list): `sorted(filter(str.isalpha, set(og)), key=og.find)`

Comment: or maybe `set(l for l in og if l.strip())`? It is really impossible to say without knowing more about the "problem"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate on the string, and keep a letter if it hasn't been seen already

```
og = "john rohn bohn"

result = []
for letter in og.replace(" ", ""):
    if letter not in result:
        result.append(letter)

print(result)  # ['j', 'o', 'h', 'n', 'r', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from the Python standard library:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

result = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(og.replace(" ", "")).keys())

print(result) #['j', 'o', 'h', 'n', 'r', 'b']
```

Comment: Since python 3.7 `dict` keeps the insertion order. So `OrderedDict` is not really needed here.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a list comprehension to create the final list considering the order and a temporary set to check whether the character was already added

```
og = "john rohn bohn"

temp = set()
list = [c for c in og if c.isalnum() and c not in temp and not temp.add(c)]

print(list)
```

Output:

```
['j', 'o', 'h', 'n', 'r', 'b']
```

Comment: Clever. Although using boolean expression to invoke a side-effect is not usually recommended. XD

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code:

```
 og = "john rohn bohn"
test = []
for i in og:
    if(i not in test):
        test.append(i)
print(test)
```

Alernative you can use list comprehensions:

```
og = "john rohn bohn"
test = []
test = [test.append(i) for i in og if i not in test]
print(test)  # reslt:['j', 'o', 'h', 'n', ' ', 'r', 'b']
```

Comment: that is equivalent to `test = list(og)` and doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @Azro I missed uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @Ervin and what @Wups has mentioned in the comment, and after some research in [What's New In Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html), which states, *the insertion-order preservation nature of dict objects has been declared to be an official part of the Python language spec.*, the simplest solution, if run under Python 3.7 or later, is:

```
og = "john rohn bohn"

list = list({c:None for c in og if c.isalnum()})

print(list)
```